# React Native: Using "setState" within Promise

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to update the state of a React Component, based on data retrieved through an API. However, I am unable to use the setState function from within the promise, as React Native always returns the following error "Type Error: _this2.setState is not a function". Here is how I am trying to achieve the following:

```
let foodList = [];
        Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                Firebase
                    .firestore()
                    .collection(`/userProfiles/${user.uid}/foodList`)
                    .get()
                    .then(foodListSnapshot => {
                        foodListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
                            foodList.push({
                                foodName: snap.data().name,
                                mealConsumed: snap.data().meal,
                                estimatedCalories: snap.data().calories,
                                dateConsumed: snap.data().date
                            });
                        });
                    }).then((foodList) => {
                        this.setState({data: foodList});
                    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
            } else {
                Alert.alert('User not signed in');
            }
        });
```

My goal is to have the component re-render, once the state's data field has been updated.

I have tried also using `bind.this` however as I'm quite new to React Native, I have been unsuccessful in figuring it out so far. If someone could help me out with this, I would be extremely appreciative! :)

Comment: Try to change to this: `onAuthStateChanged((user) => {`. This way the function will bind outer scope.

Comment: @ischenkodv - You're seriously amazing! I've been struggling with this one issue for the past few hours, thank you so very much! 

I don't suppose you could explain why exactly this solution worked, when manually binding the API calls didn't?

Comment: @Vilitaria The function `function() {}` doesn't bind outer scope while `() => {}` binds it. That's the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `function(user)` to `(user) => {}`, because function() does not bind the outer scope(state). So it would look something like this:

```js
let foodList = [];
        Firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                Firebase
                    .firestore()
                    .collection(`/userProfiles/${user.uid}/foodList`)
                    .get()
                    .then(foodListSnapshot => {
                        foodListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
                            foodList.push({
                                foodName: snap.data().name,
                                mealConsumed: snap.data().meal,
                                estimatedCalories: snap.data().calories,
                                dateConsumed: snap.data().date
                            });
                        });
                    }).then((foodList) => {
                        this.setState({data: foodList});
                    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
            } else {
                Alert.alert('User not signed in');
            }
        });
```

That will make `state` available inside of that function.